# Jackson. ClassCastException while value get from a generic class

Tags: java, spring, generics, jackson, dto

I have a DTO

```
public class FilterSet {

    @JsonProperty("price")
    private IntervalFilter<Double> priceFilter;

    public IntervalFilter<Double> getPriceFilter() {
        return priceFilter;
    }

    public void setPriceFilter(IntervalFilter<Double> priceFilter) {
        this.priceFilter = priceFilter;
    }

    public static class IntervalFilter<T> {

        private IntervalValue<T> value;

        public IntervalValue<T> getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(IntervalValue value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public static class IntervalValue<T> {

            private T from;

            private T to;

            public T getFrom() {
                return from;
            }

            public void setFrom(T from) {
                this.from = from;
            }

            public T getTo() {
                return to;
            }

            public void setTo(T to) {
                this.to = to;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I send priceFilter {"price": { "value" : { "from" : 1.1, "to" : 1.2 } } } it's ok.
When I send priceFilter {"price": { "value" : { "from" : 1.0, "to" : 2.0 } } } and try to get Double value:

```
Double priceFrom = priceFilter.getValue().getFrom();
```

I see java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

What did I do wrong?

**More Info:**
Json:  {"price":{ "value" : { "from" : 1.0, "to" : 2.1 } } }

I have an object FilterSet from Spring controller. And there I can see a field "priceFilter" (type IntervalFilter) with field "value" (type IntervalValue) and field "from" (type Integer) and "to" (type Double).

```
public String getLinks(
            @RequestBody FilterSet filterData
    ) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Would it be possible to provide the entire DTO? E.g. there is no way of accessing the internal data of the `FilterSet` class since there are no functions available. Furthermore, I can not see how the JSON you provided can be converted to a FilterSet (but rather to a `IntervalFilter`), is that the full JSON?

Comment: I added getters & setters to a DTO example to avoid confuse. Yes, it's not a full json, fixed it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error can be reproduced by using the following JSON (where an integer is used).

```
 {"price":{ "value" : { "from" : 1, "to" : 2.1 } } }
```

To avoid this this problem all references of `IntervalValue` must be declared using the generic type (i.e use the ´<>`), otherwise the raw type is used and it will be considered to be an`Integer`in the example above (which causes the`ClassCastException`). When you instead use the generic type, a value of type`Double` is forced since it is declared in the code. Hence, if you change the setter to the following it works as expected:

```
public void setValue(IntervalValue<T> value) {
     this.value = value;
}
```

Notice that the parameter is of type `IntervalValue<T>`, not `IntervalValue` as in the original code.

Comment: Yes, this is it! My inattention. Thx